# How can I parse rows in a table that are composed of cells that aren't just <td> but an occasional <th> cell?

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am still new to `python` and I'm very new to `BeautifulSoup`. I have been working on creating a web scraper using `BeautifulSoup` to go in and parse department directories from websites.  The directories are structured in an HTML table. As expected most of the cells are `td` tags; however, there is an occasional cell that is a `th` tag that I also need to parse.

A majority of these pages are `.aspx` and I read that in order to scrape these, a web driver is necessary. This is my initial code, I have mostly been BeautifulSoup used with requests so I am not sure if this is correct regarding using it with a web driver.

```
url = "https://webberathletics.com/staff.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\bobby\OneDrive\Documents\MyPrograms\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
contacts_list = []
```

I am going to be adding a lot more URLs for the scraper to parse, so I am trying to make the scraper as dynamic as possible meaning it will scrape tables that contain rows that have a `th` cell and others that don't.  Below is what I currently have.

I want it to parse the cell whether it is a `td` or a `th`.

```
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td', 'th')

    if len(cells) > 0:
        col1 = cells[0].text.strip()
        col2 = cells[1].text.strip()
        col3 = cells[2].text.strip()
        col4 = cells[3].text.strip()

        contact = {'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3': col3, 'col4': col4}
        contacts_list.append(contact)

        print(contacts_list)
```

At the moment it won't print at all but it runs, so I'm not sure if it is working correctly or not. But even if it did print, I'm unsure if I am going about this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to be scraping tables with the `<table>` tag, I'd opt to just use Pandas `.read_html()`. Does the hard work for you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


url = "https://webberathletics.com/staff.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
df = tables[1]
df = df[pd.isnull(df['Image'])].drop(['Image'], axis=1)

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
```

**Edit:**

If you want to keep those "sub-headings":

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


url = "https://webberathletics.com/staff.aspx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
df = tables[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! It worked perfectly, the only challenge I have now which I didn't mention before because I was parsing the entire table is the department headings that divide the table.  I need to include those in the parse so that when format the data I know who is in which department.  Is there a way to add that in as a field or column?

Comment: Well aren't those departments also in their titles?

Comment: You could have those included in the table, it just makes it a little messy. So you'd have to do a little clean up work. But I added that in the solution in the edit

Comment: No they're not, in this instance for this specific website they are but on others if I were to continue using athletic directories some would just say `head coach` without noting the sport, so I would need to know the department to know which sport they coach.

Comment: ah gotcha. Cool.

Comment: make sure to accept the solution if this worked out for you